# Why this code is not compiling on ruby 1.9 but is on ruby 1.8?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8

Sorry for the title, I don't know how this syntax is called.

For instance:

```
ary = [ [11, [1]], [22, [2, 2]], [33, [3, 3, 3]] ]
# want to get [ [11, 1], [22, 2], [33, 3] ]
```

Ruby 1.8

```
ary.map{|x, (y,)| [x, y] }
#=> [[11, 1], [22, 2], [33, 3]]

ary.map{|x, (y)| [x, y] }
#Syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
#ary.map{|x, (y)| [x, y] }
#                ^
```

Ruby 1.9

```
ary.map{|x, (y,)| [x, y] }
#SyntaxError: (irb):95: syntax error, unexpected ')'
#ary.map{|x, (y,)| [x, y] }
#                ^

ary.map{|x, (y)| [x, y] }
#=> [[11, 1], [22, 2], [33, 3]]
```

※ *I am not asking for a way to get the wanted array.*

I would like to know **why this piece of code is working is either one of the Ruby's version but not both**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While generally Ruby 1.9 is a lot more lenient about trailing commas in lists and list-like representations than previous versions, there are some new occasions where it will throw a syntax error. This seems to be one. Ruby 1.9 treats this as strictly as a method definition and won't allow that stray comma.

You've also seem to run up against an edge-case bug in Ruby 1.8.7 that has been corrected. The list expansion method doesn't seem to work with only one item.

A quick fix in this case might be:

```
ary.map{|x, (y,_)| [x, y] }
```

In this case `_` functions as a *whatever* variable.

In both versions you should get:

```
[[11, 1], [22, 2], [33, 3]]
```

Comment: If the trailing comma was needed in `Ruby 1.8`, does it mean there was some kind of rule that disappeared ?

Comment: I don't think it was needed so much as it side-stepped the problem. The entire block argument semantics got a huge overhaul in 1.9. Optional arguments with defaults and `*args` type catch-alls are now supported. This quirky behavior of not allowing a list with one item, but not caring if the second is actually named seems to have been removed.